# surfaces $F$ and $G$ are tangent if and only if $\nabla{F}\times{\nabla{G}}=\mathbf{0}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose that two surfaces are given by the equations $F(x,y,z)=c$ and $G(x,y,z)=k$.  Moreover, suppose that these surfaces intersect at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.  Show that the surfaces are tangent at $(x_0,y_0,z_z)$ if and only if
$$\nabla{F}\times\nabla{G}=\mathbf{0}$$
Here's my attempt...

$\Rightarrow$
Since the surfaces are tangent, they have the same tangent plane.  These tangent planes can be represented by different equations, but must only differ by a scalar.  Let $\mathbf{x}_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0), a,b \in\mathbb{R}$. Thus
$$a[F_x(\mathbf{x_0})(x-x_o)+F_y(\mathbf{x_0})(y-y_o)+F_z(\mathbf{x_0})(z-z_o)]=b[G_x(\mathbf{x_0})(x-x_o)+G_y(\mathbf{x_0})(y-y_o)+G_z(\mathbf{x_0})(z-z_o)]$$
Which implies 
$$F_i(\mathbf{x}_0)=\frac{b}{a}G_i(\mathbf{x}_0), i=x,y,z.$$
Since these partial derivatives only differ by a scalar, they are linearly dependent and thus parallel.  Since they are parallel, $\nabla{F}\times\nabla{G}=\mathbf{0}$

Now the other way is where I'm having trouble

$\Leftarrow$  Suppose $\nabla{F}\times\nabla{G}=\mathbf{0}$.  This implies three things; either $\nabla{F}=\mathbf{0}, \nabla{G}=\mathbf{0}$ (or both), or $\nabla{F}||\nabla{G}$.  If either $\nabla{F}$ or $\nabla{G}=\mathbf{0}$, the surface represented by $F$ or $G$ is a plane.  It is from here I get lost as to where to go.  If I assume that they are parallel, I feel as though my only path is the reverse of $\Rightarrow$, which I don't believe is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion that "if $\nabla F=0$ then the surface represented by $F$ is a plane" is incorrect.  If the gradient vanishes at a point, then the locus of the equation may have a singularity at the point, so that the tangent plane is undefined. If you check your textbook you will probably notice that they require the gradient to be nonvanishing.

Comment: Okay, so where does that take me from there?  So if $\nabla{F}=\mathbf{0}$, then it is either a plane or the tangent plane is undefined and I approach the parallel gradient argument.  But how do I attack the parallel gradient agrument, or is there another angle I'm not seeing?  And how does the $\Rightarrow$ argument look?

Comment: If the gradients are nonzero and parallel this means that the normal vectors of the two planes are proportional and hence the planes are the same. I would reformulate the argument by showing that both conditions are equivalent to a third condition, namely that the normal vectors of the two planes are proportional. There is no need to write everything in coordinates once you've understood what is going on.

Comment: Okay, i think I understand.  Once we use the normal vector argument, since the normal vectors are proportional, and we already know they intersect at a point $\mathbf{0}$, we can deduce their cross product is $\mathbf{0}$.